# Flutter: Show Modal Bottom Sheet over/replacing Bottom Navigation Bar (without barrier)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to replicate some functionality similar to Google Maps for my own Flutter application. Also map based, I'd like the user to be able to select a point of interest and have the option to navigate to said location.

When they hit 'navigate', I want a bottom sheet to appear in place (or on top of) the existing Bottom Navigation Bar that I have for tab-based navigation.

`showModalBottomSheet()` does this, however it has a barrier which prevents the user from interacting with the parent view. I need it without the barrier.

`showBottomSheet()` doesn't have the barrier but it also doesn't get placed on top of the Bottom Navigation Bar.

Is there some solution in order to have this functionality? The only thing I can think of is to add the Bottom Navigation Bar to a Container that will show/hide based on whether the user is navigating or not, but I feel it's quite a hacked solution and was hoping for something more elegant.

I've attached a couple of images below:

- The first screenshot shows Google Maps' standard view on iOS that has the Bottom Navigation Bar.
- The second screenshot shows the 'pre-navigation' view which is a Bottom Sheet which is placed on top of (or in place of) the Bottom Navigation Bar. This is the view that I'm trying to replicate.

[image: This is the main view with the Bottom Navigation Bar at the bottom]

[image: This is the 'pre-navigation' view that shows a bottom sheet without / on top of the Bottom Navigation Bar]

Comment: Did you find any good solution? I have the same problem :D

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what Guillaume answered with below. I wrapped the Scaffold that holds the BottomNavigationBar into a Stack widget, then added my custom navigation view on top of that and set it to appear if the user entered 'navigation mode'. I've posted my code below for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68208539/1280479

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I've found would be to wrap the `Scaffold` widget containing your `bottomNavigationBar` into another `Scaffold`. The idea would be to display your modal inside the parent `Scaffold` so it would be on top of the `bottomNavigationBar` inside the child `Scaffold`.

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _showModal = false;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  PersistentBottomSheetController _bottomSheetController;

  void _showOrHide(bool show) {
    _showModal = show;
    if (_showModal) {
      _bottomSheetController = _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
        (_) => Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Text('This is a BottomSheet'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      );
    } else {
      if (_bottomSheetController != null) _bottomSheetController.close();
      _bottomSheetController = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              label: 'Business',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Show/Hide Modal Bottom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () => _showOrHide(!_showModal),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example I am keeping a reference to my parent `ScaffoldState` through `_scaffoldKey` so I can call my `showBottomSheet` on the correct `Scaffold`.

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/608322eef3ce4eb7d8d04a94573ae201)

**Screenshot:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use `useRootNavigator: true` in `showBottomModalSheet`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solve this was similar to Guillaume's answer. Wrapping the `Scaffold` widget in a `Stack` widget allowed me to place a custom view on top of the BottomNavigationBar and I simply set it to appear when the user had entered 'Navigation Mode'.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          body: CupertinoPageScaffold(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: _selectedPage,
              children: pageList,
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: _tabItems(),
            currentIndex: _selectedPage,
            selectedItemColor: DoralColors.darkBlue,
            onTap: _onTabTapped,
          ),
        ),
        if (_navigating == true)
          _navigationView(destination, destinationAddress),
      ],
    );
  }
```

In the code above, `_navigationView` is my custom navigation view. I opted not to use any modal view in the end as I couldn't get it to act as I would have liked.