# Is there a way hide the barrier of showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog

### Edit: I found the answer: [Flutter: Show Modal Bottom Sheet over/replacing Bottom Navigation Bar (without barrier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383662/flutter-show-modal-bottom-sheet-over-replacing-bottom-navigation-bar-without-b)

### `showBottomSheet` will not work for this, because it's drawn below drawers. I want to draw above drawers.

In my UI, I want to display a notification on top of the app, without interfering with the user experience.

Is there a way to hide the barrier, shrink it, or allow gestures to pass through it?

### 1. This code shows the message below the drawer.

`showSnackBar()` also does this.

```
 void show(String message) {
    _globals.scaffoldKey.currentState!
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration), () {
          try {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          } on Exception {}
        });
        return Container(
            color: backgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Wrap(children: [
              Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
              )
            ]));
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

### 2. This code returns an error, "No Scaffold Widget found," though I don't suspect it would work any differently than the above anyway.

```
  void show(String message) {
    showBottomSheet<void>(
      context: _globals.navKey.currentState!.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration), () {
          try {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          } on Exception {}
        });
        return Container(
            color: backgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Wrap(children: [
              Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
              )
            ]));
      },
    );
  }
```

### 3. This code shows the message on top, but has the grey barrier in the way, which is cumbersome.

```
  void show(String message) {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: _globals.navKey.currentState!.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration), () {
          try {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          } on Exception {}
        });
        return Container(
            color: backgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Wrap(children: [
              Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
              )
            ]));
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383662/flutter-show-modal-bottom-sheet-over-replacing-bottom-navigation-bar-without-b